# Need help to get a value of an xPath in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, bots, puppeteer

I want to get the value of an exact xpath, that has a value of 1,400. Can not use any span or label class name because their are multiple classes with the same class or label name. So i have found out i have to use the Xpath. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<span class="currency-coins value">1,400</span>
```

Full xpath:

```
/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div/section[2]/div[2]/section/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]/text()
```

[image: Image of the Code]

Comment: While it is indeed possible to use xPath, are you sure there is no other way? Could you share the URL of the target site?

Comment: @Vaviloff the page is a site where i am loged in

Answer (score 1):

If the label is unique you can try:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Kjop na')][0]/following-sibling::*
```